# 20.04 provides only 4 usable character screens (vs 6 on 16.04)

Tags: command-line, 16.04, 18.04, login

20.04 provides only 4 usable character screens (vs 6 on 16.04)
On 20.04 the login/GUI screen is on F2, F1 login/prompt to another GUI screen
and F7 is unusable, so I only have 4 character login screens
On 16.04 the GUI login screen was on F7 & I had 6 character login screens
Does 20.04 provide any way to restore screen use as on 16.04 ?
or to use more screens F8-F12 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increase the number of TTY consoles?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124397/how-do-i-increase-the-number-of-tty-consoles)

Comment: Yes great  my updates: vi /etc/systemd/logind.conf  NAutoVTS=10 ReserveVT=10