Virtual consoles do not show a way to log in
On my Ubuntu 22.04 installation, I am able to switch virtual consoles with ctrl-alt-F1/F2/... like normal.  F7 shows the GUI, also as expected.  However, none of the consoles F1-F6 show a shell or login prompt.  They all just show the last messages from the kernel on boot.  There is no cursor or any indication of interactivity.  I have no way to log in.
How can I fix this issue and use the text-mode virtual consoles?
Other possibly useful info:

This is an upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04
I have an nVidia 3060 card, and I'm running the official nVidia driver.  Supposedly, using the official driver can cause issues with vt's, but I have run the mitigation steps that I found, namely to uncomment GRUB_TERMINAL and GRUB_GFXMODE in /etc/default/grub and then reload grub.  Those changes had no discernible effect.


vt7 hasn't been used in awhile. Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124397/how-do-i-increase-the-number-of-tty-consoles  The number defaults to 6, but is configurable.

All I can say is that on my system, vt7 has the GUI, and vt6 is just like vt1-vt5

After switching to (empty) VT6 and back, does journalctl -xe -u getty@tty6 say anything interesting?

No new messages appear, and the last message (presumably from the last boot) seems normal:
A start job for unit getty@tty6.service has finished successfully.

I solved this my adding "nomodeset" to my linux default options line in /etc/default/grub, like so:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
Then run update-grub to load that configuration.
